# Find an example of a series satisfying two properties

Tags: sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples, divergent-series

Find a series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n$ such that:

- The general term is vanishing, that is $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} a_n = 0$.
- The sequence of partial sums $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k $ is bounded .
- The series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n$ diverges.

Comment: How could a bounded sequence diverge? Are you sure that the exercise requires divergence? Does it ask for non convergence, perhaps?

Comment: @zar Diverges means "does not converge."

Comment: You can take the harmonic series and give each term a sign s.t. you flip the sign if $s_n$ reaches 1 or -1, so the partial sum is always in $(-2,2)$, but the series does not converge (as it reaches 1 and -1 infinitely often).

Comment: @Clement-c Ah, that's bad... Divergence and non convergence are two different things

Comment: @zar Not really.... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series "In mathematics, a divergent series is an infinite series that is not convergent"

Comment: I'm italian, and here in Italy all books define divergence as $s_n\to\pm\infty$. Whereas non convergence corresponds to the fact that $s_n$ has no limit.

Comment: I'm sorry for the inconvenience, I meant of course "does not converge".

Comment: But the most common and standard definition does state that "A sequence which does not converge is said to be divergent."  (see, again, [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence) and the corresponding reference [2], for instance).

Comment: There is "correct" definition. In the above case it should be clear what is ment out of context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 0}$ made of "chunks" of increasing size. The $k$-th chunk has $2^k$ terms, each of them equal to $\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k}$.

The series $\sum_{n} a_n$ will have the properties you want.

Answer (score 2):

$$
a=\{1,-1,\frac12,\frac12,-\frac12,-\frac12,\frac13,\frac13,\frac13,-\frac13,-\frac13,-\frac13,\frac14,\frac14,\frac14,\frac14,-\frac14,-\frac14,-\frac14,-\frac14,\ldots\}
$$